# failed to clone https //git.drupal.org/project/coder.git git was not found

Tags: git, drupal, drupal-8

I tried to install Drupal Commerce 2.x but it show the error failed to clone https //git.drupal.org/project/coder.git git was not found help me to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install module via drush. You can follow below command line.

```
1) drush dl commerce
2) drush en commerce
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Composer in order to install all required dependencies. From [Commerce 2 documention](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation):

`composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev`

Answer (score 0):

You can download it directly from the project page and install in your drupal site.
[Drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)